# Materialized Views Refresh from Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have materialized views refresh commands like execute dbms_mview.refresh('Table_Name','F') and want to run these commands together at once.

I want to refresh tables from Informatica using PRESQL or POSTSQL. Tried separating commands using ";" and "," and "\;" then also session log shows invalid SQL statements. We use oracle database and am able to successfully run these commands there.

Is it possible to refresh them using "execute dbms_mview.refresh('Table_Name','F')" in PRESQL? Is there other way of doing this like adding commands in begin and end without using "execute"?

Thank you :)

**** Added a working solution ****

Comment: Why not use a stored procedure transformation configured to run preload then you can put all the materialised view refresh commands within that procedure

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
begin
dbms_mview.refresh('VIEW_1','F')\;
dbms_mview.refresh('VIEW_2','F')\;
end\;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, use ; as a command separator...

Can you make it work with one command (no separator)?
Look in the session log to see the exact command being executed, and run that from an sql tool to get better (and faster) feedback from the database.

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried executing them separated by ";" and it says invalid SQL statements in the session log. These commands work fine in the SQL developer.